# How to make font size customizable in a macOS app

Tags: macos, swiftui, font-size, dynamictype

I’m creating a cross-platform app, iOS  and macOS (not MacOS Catalyst), in SwiftUI.

I’m supporting Dynamic Type through the `.font(.title)`  `.font(.caption)`  etc. modifiers.

This works great on iOS, however MacOS doesn’t support Dynamic Type.

I know users can change the font size on their Mac system wide through the display settings, but I would like to add an app preference where users can change the font size only for my app. Something similar like, for example, the mail app offers (Format > Style > Bigger)

I’m quite an experienced iOS dev,but this is my first MacOS app and my first real SwiftUI-only app. I’ve searched google and SO for half a day but can not find a way to do this.

Can this be done? Perhaps there is some kind of modifier to scale the font with a factor (and I could make that factor a global variable that would increase or decrease by the user changing this setting), or perhaps there is another way?

Comment: I was thinking EnvironmentValue `dynamicTypeSize`, but the doc says: "On macOS, this value cannot be changed by users and does not affect the text size."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach with a view modifier `.dynamicFont` that takes a `factor`.

Be aware that the standard sizes (for factor 1.0) reflect the standard macOS styles. You might cover iOS sizes as well there if you want to use it cross platform.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            GroupBox {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                        .font(.title)
                    
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                        .font(.body)
                    
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                        .font(.caption)
                }
            }
            
            // example use
            GroupBox {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                        .dynamicFont(.title, factor: 1.2)
                    
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                        .dynamicFont(.body, factor: 1.2)
                    
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                        .dynamicFont(.caption, factor: 1.2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}




enum DynamicFontStyle {
    case largeTitle
    case title
    case headline
    case body
    case caption
    // ...
    
    // the standard sizes and weights are for MacOS!! and taken from
    // https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/foundations/typography/#specifications
    
    func specs(factor: Double) -> Font {
        switch self {
        case .largeTitle:
            return Font.system(size: 26 * factor, weight: .regular)
        case .title:
            return Font.system(size: 22 * factor, weight: .regular)
        case .headline:
            return Font.system(size: 13 * factor, weight: .bold)
        case .body:
            return Font.system(size: 13 * factor, weight: .regular)
        case .caption:
            return Font.system(size: 10  * factor, weight: .regular)
        }
        // ...
    }
}


// View expension for ease of use
extension View {
    func dynamicFont(_ style: DynamicFontStyle = .body, factor: Double = 1) -> some View {
        self
            .modifier(DynamicFontModifier(style: style, factor: factor))
    }
}


// View Modifier
struct DynamicFontModifier: ViewModifier  {
    
    let style: DynamicFontStyle
    let factor: Double
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(style.specs(factor: factor))
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great. Let me give this a try on Monday. Will report back and upvote etc if this work!! Thank you so much in advance!!!